# При Debug выскакивает ошибка (javac error : error: illegal character: \0)

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Пишу приложение для андроида на Xamarin

при Debug выскакивает ошибка:

```
javac error : error: illegal character: \0
```

При Release её нет, как можно исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости удалить "\0" в том месте, куда указывает дебагер. А в дебаге у вас работает потому, что там применены другие настройки, вот поэтому там и работает